# Arithmetic sets problem

Tags: arithmetic

I need help with a set problem

Given:

$$A=\{(\sqrt{n}+2) \in \Bbb Z \ /\ \ 16\le n^2 \le 1296 \}$$

$$B=\{({3m-2}) \in  A \ /\ \ 4 \le 4m+3 \le 17 \}$$

Calculate the value of :
$$n(A)\times n(B)$$

So far I've got into $$ A = \{-8;-7;-6;-5;-4;4;5;6;7;8\} $$
$$B= \{4;5;6;7;8\}$$

therefore 
$$n(A) = 10$$
$$n(B) = 5$$
 However I don't know if this is correct as the result does not match any of the options given as answer.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite: The symbol $\sqrt{n}$ usually refers to the nonnegative square root of $n$, so $A$ should only contain positive numbers. Now

$$\sqrt{1296} = \sqrt{6^4} = 36$$

so the smallest element of $A$ corresponds to $\sqrt{4} + 2$, while the largest corresponds to $\sqrt{36} + 2$; that is, it's equivalent to write

$$A = \{\sqrt{n} + 2 : 4 \le n \le 36\}$$

Comment: wouldn't it be the same to write $$ A = \{ \sqrt{n}+2 : 4 \le \sqrt{n}+2 \le 8 \} $$ ?

Comment: No, that is not the same because you don't restrict $\sqrt n$ to naturals so $2+\sqrt 5$ would be included. You are thinking in the right direction.

Comment: Okay so now after correcting I got 
$$ A=\{4;5;6;7;8\} \ \& \  B = \{4;5;6;7;8\}$$ but the result of n(a)x n(b) still differs from the given options, Maybe i'm still doing it wrong? Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**.  The symbol $\sqrt{\ }$ means the positive square root.  It doesn't mean plus- or- minus  unless you actually write $\pm$.